# When does consumer implemented on blocking queue stop listening to messages

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, java.util.concurrent

Hi have written a simple producer consumer problem using LinkedblockingQueue. My producer writes 1 to 10 in the queue and consumer reads from the queue using while loop inside run method as 
Below

```
    while(true){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consumed: "+ sharedQueue.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}
```

As per definition of blocking queue, blocking queue is blocked if there are no messages in the queue and it waits until message is put in queue. Because I am use a while loop ,will my consumer be blocked indefinitely?

Comment: You've answered your own question. It blocks until a message is put in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: why not try running it and see for yourself?